# Next.js How can I redirect to same path but adding query parameters using next.config.js redirects?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying when user visits like `/mypage` add query parameters like `/mypage?offer=abc`

I tried something like:

```
 {
    source: '/mypage',
    destination: '/mypage?offer=abc',
    permanent: false,
  },
```

Initially works, but now anytime that user visits something like `/mypage?offer=123` is being redirected to `/mypage?offer=abc` so I want the redirection only when the url doesn't have query string parameters

I also tried with regex, like:

```
{
    source: '/(mypage$)',
    destination: '/mypage?offer=abc',
    permanent: false,
  },
```

But I get `redirected you too many times`

Comment: Why would you do this? Please elaborate.

Comment: I need to add default parameters when the user comes from a link without them

Comment: I do understand this already. It just makes no sense for me and I can't come up with a meaningful use case. You still did not describe your use case. The user comes from which sources (you control the sources, external, ...)? What are the defaults, you want to transmit? User specific, referrer specific, always the same? I'll answer more details in an answer. Comments are a pain to edit.

Comment: Time has gone. Please select an answer or answer your question and select it as resolved. This helps keep Stack Overflow tidy.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [middleware to intercept requests](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware).
2. You can use the [`redirect`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/redirecting#redirect-function) function for fine-grained redirect logic.

I would try to fix this at the source (links, event handlers) or extract the defaults at the target (page) by examining the source (referrer, header), just to give some wild guesses.